# How to Retrieve an image when inserted from backend using php

Tags: php, mysql

I've used the below code to store and get the images from the backend. The images are getting stored but it is not getting converted to base64 format...

```
$fruit_img = addslashes($_FILES['fruit_img']['tmp_name']);
$name = addslashes($_FILES['fruit_img']['name']);
$fruit_img = file_get_contents($fruit_img);
$fruit_img = base64_encode($image);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo '<img height ="300" width="300" src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$row[2].' "> ';
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: it's hard to guess your incomplete code

Answer (score 1):

I presume your code represents storing the data here:

```
$fruit_img = addslashes($_FILES['fruit_img']['tmp_name']);
$name = addslashes($_FILES['fruit_img']['name']);
$fruit_img = file_get_contents($fruit_img);
$fruit_img = base64_encode($image);
```

And retrieving the data here:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo '<img height ="300" width="300" src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$row[2].' "> ';
    echo $row[0];
}
```

If that is the case, you have simply mislabeled a variable in this line:

```
$fruit_img = base64_encode($image);
```

$image has not been assigned any value previously.

```
$fruit_img = base64_encode($fruit_img);
```

If that is not the case, please post additional (complete insert and read) code.